# Why does Laravel redirect to a wrong id after DB::listen?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I would like to store every query I run inside my application. To do that, I've created a "loggers" table, a Logger modal and this function inside my boot AppServiceProvider

```
DB::listen(function($query) {
    $logger = new Logger;
    $logger->query = str_replace('"', '', $query->sql);
    $logger->bindings = json_encode($query->bindings);
    $logger->created_at = Carbon::now();
    $logger->save();
});
```

Well, anytime I run an insert query, Laravel returns the loggers table ID instead of the model last inserted ID.
Why on earth does this happen?

```
public function store(CycleRequest $request) {
    $appointment = new Appointment;
    $appointment-> ... same data ...
    $appointment->save();

    if ( ! $errors ) ){
        $msg['redirect'] = route('appointments.edit', $appointment);

        // The page redirects to last logger id
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do triggers so I recommend use events for this, o maybe you can take the structure of you table "loggers" and do two differents querys each time that you do querys.

Comment: Db::listen method in AppServiceProviders already triggers any time a run a query. I was just wondering why the query returns the ID of the loggers table and not the model last inserted id.

Answer (score 0):

After searching a lot, I found a solution creating a Middleware. Hope this may help someone else.

I've created a QueryLogMiddleware and registered in 'web' middleware, but you may put it everywhere you want:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
   \DB::enableQueryLog();

   return $next($request);
}

public function terminate($request, $response)
{
   $queries = \DB::getQueryLog();

   foreach ($queries as $query)
   {
      // Save $query to the database
      // $query["query"]
      // $query["bindings"]
      ...
   }

   \DB::disableQueryLog();
   \DB::flushQueryLog();
}
```